# Small exclamation icon over my STS project icon

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am working on Struts project using the Spring Source Toolsuite IDE.

When there are complier errors or something, a red X mark or yellow exclamation mark appear over the icon for my project.

But even after I made sure there are no complier errors, I got this exclamation mark in my project icon. My project is building and running successfully and I am getting the proper output.

Why is it there? How can I find out what it is complaining about?

Comment: Click Window -> Show View -> Problems and you'll see the list of errors/warnings and take it from there.

Comment: Thanks lobster. If you can post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, very thoughtful of you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click Window -> Show View -> Problems and you'll see the list of errors/warnings and you can take it from there.

Comment: In the version of eclipse I'm using "Problems" didn't show up in the list. I had to select "Other..." and do a search for Problems, which appeared under the General section. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

As ptsw pointed out, too:
If the *Problems* item isn't visible in *Window* -> *Show View* menu, choose *Other...* instead and select **Problems** in the General group to view the Problems pane:

[image: Screenshot]